# Xaml grid image gallery with preview

Tags: facebook, xaml, data-binding, imageview

I would like to create an image gallery in my win8 app where the user can select a thumbnail image and preview it in a larger area. I am obtaining the images from Facebook and using data binding to a grid view for the thumbnails. However, I cannot seem to find how to allow the user to select the image and display a large version of the image in a separate area.

Basically I want to set the source of the rectangle/area to the source url of the selected thumbnail. Is this possible?

So far I've got the following but the view box doesn't display anything:

```
<GridView x:Name="photosView"  ItemsSource="{Binding Photos}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="762,462,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="514" Height="166" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource picTemp}" IsItemClickEnabled="True">
        <GridView.DataContext>
            <ViewModel:FacebookPhotosData/>
        </GridView.DataContext>
    </GridView> 

    <Viewbox x:Name="Preview" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="379" Margin="778,48,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="480">
        <Viewbox.DataContext>
            <ViewModel:FacebookPhotosData/>
        </Viewbox.DataContext>
    </Viewbox>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself. I used an image and the ItemClicked event to change the source.

```
<GridView x:Name="photosView" ItemsSource="{Binding Photos}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="762,462,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="514" Height="166" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource picTemp}" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="photosView_ItemClick">
        <GridView.DataContext>
            <ViewModel:FacebookPhotosData/>
        </GridView.DataContext>
    </GridView>
    <Image x:Name="Preview" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="379" Margin="778,48,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="480"/>
```

In the event handler, I set the image to show the picture indicated by the URI in the selected image.